# Eclipse Find Regular Expression

Tags: regex, eclipse

I am trying to find multiple occurrences of some text in Eclipse in multiple files but not able to write the correct regular expression for the same.

I have multiple occurrences of text which matches the following pattern

```
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/**cxf-extension**-soap.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/**cxf-extension**-http.xml" />
```

After **cxf-extension** there could be any thing.

So I want to find out all such occurrences which start with "< import" has the work "cxf-extension" and ends with "/>".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will work:

```
<import.*?cxf-extension.*?\/>
```

And here are some tests:
http://www.regex101.com/r/yX3mH3

Comment: There is actually no need for escaping the `/` in Eclipse, since the separator does not present for the regex (the one on regex101 needs that because it has separator).

Comment: @nhahtdh Eclipse has it's own regex compiler? I was assuming that he just didn't specify his language. Also, I like to put the `\` for clarity. It won't effect the run time of the regex, correct?

Comment: I guess Eclipse uses the same syntax for Java regex (I tested a bit, and it seems so). Performance probably won't matter - just that it is not necessary, since the regex will mean the same thing without the \.